# Keep the column names of a data.table in a user-defined function

Tags: r, data.table

Let's say that I have the following `data.table` object

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(
  x = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
  y = c(1, 1, 3, 4, 5),
  z = c(1, 1, 1, 4, 5)
)
```

I want to be able to count the number of unique values of any stats, raised it to a power `y` and return it in a `data.table`, keeping the name of the stats.

I want to do something like the following

```
foo <- function(stats, y){
  lapply(stats, function(stat){length(unique(stat))^y})
}

dt[, foo(.(x, y), 2)]
##     V1 V2
##  1: 25 16
```

but I expect the output to be

```
dt[, foo(.(x, y), 2)]
##      x  y
##  1: 25 16
```

Note that doing this

```
dt[, foo(.(x=x, y=y), 2)]
##      x  y
##  1: 25 16
```

or this

```
dt[, foo(data.table(x, y), 2)]
##      x  y
##  1: 25 16
```

will work, but I think the syntax I suggested earlier looks better. Is it possible to tweak the `foo` function to do so or I have to, in some way, tweak the `.(` function directly in the `data.table` package?

Comment: does this need to be `data.table`? Would a `tidyverse` solution be helpful?

Comment: Is there any reason why the `lapply` has to be in the function? What if the function just worked on a vector and left the looping outside - `foo2 <- function(x,n) length(unique(x))^n` and then `dt[, lapply(.SD, foo2, n=2), .SDcols=c("x","y")]` for instance?

Comment: I want the function to be the most simple to use for inexperienced users. That's why I would have prefer to handle the looping on my side (inside the `foo` function) so that users would not have to handle it another way than passing the columns they want the function to apply as an argument.

Comment: I guess this colwise FR will help: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1063 You could comment there if you have thoughts on the simplest/best syntax, I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two potential workarounds. The first one is what you are requesting:

```
foo <- function(stat, x){
  DF <- lapply(stat, function(stat2){length(unique(stat2))^x})
  names(DF) <- sapply(substitute(stat)[-1], deparse)
  return(DF)
}

dt[, foo(.(x, y), 2)]
    x  y
1: 25 16
```

This one I think is probably just as user friendly and might be more powerful. If you asking about `data.table`, you should try to utilize its strengths.

```
foo2 <- function(DT, exponent, SD_cols , by_v = NULL){

  DT[,
     lapply(.SD, function(stat) {length(unique(stat))^exponent}),
     .SDcols = SD_cols,
     by = by_v]
}

foo2(dt, 2, c('x','y'), by_v = 'z')
   z x y
1: 1 9 4
2: 4 1 1
3: 5 1 1

foo2(dt, 2, c('x', 'y'))
    x  y
1: 25 16
```

Comment: Yep, I think it makes more sense to add `DT` to the function.

Comment: I don't want to limit the use of the `foo` function to a `data.table` necessarily. I want the fonction to work as long as the user provide a (named or not) list as the first argument. For the `foo` function, the `data.table` should be nothing more than a named list.

Comment: @J.P.LeCavalier see edit. I think including the ```dt``` in the ```foo``` call is still a pretty good way to go.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, that's what I was working for! Don't worry, I'll use `data.table` strength if the user provides one. I was only asking for my curiosity when I saw that the `data.table` was not parsed as a named list as I supposed it would be. This is only a very simple reproducible example, my case is much more complex and includes a different implementation of the `foo` function depending if used with a `list` or a `data.table`. Thanks again :)